# Access a project from a shared direcdtory and create pyc file in another directory

Tags: python, linux

I've shared a project under my home directory. `/home/myid/share/project`, and let everyone know that they can run this project by just following line

```
import sys   
sys.path.append("/home/myid/share")

import project as pj
```

Now, i have given access to read and execute (run) the project, but there are files which are created under `/home/myid/share/project/__pycache__/*.pyc` with the owner who is running this project, and i don't have permission to delete these files, what can i do to either delete these files or these files should created under their own directory.